# useState no setea valores inmediatamente en React Native

Tags: react-native

Estoy utilizando react native sin expo, al intentar setear un valor con UseState no setea inmediatamente,
y no puedo obtener los valores en otra funcion.

este seria mi codigo:

```
const [grillaData, setGrillaData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        getGrillaApi().then((response)=>{
            setGrillaData(response);
            pressed('Lun', 0);
        })
    
}, []);
```

setGrillaData no setea y al ejecutar la funcion pressed no tengo los valores de grillaData

```
const pressed = async (categoria, index) => {
    console.log(grillaData); // ningun valor esta vacio
}
```

como podria solucionar esto

Comment: `getGrillaAPI()` esta devolviendo algo?

Comment: sii tengo todos los resultados de un fetch

Comment: Fijate si podes compartir el código completo, alternativamente puedes crear un [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: Leoh ten en cuenta que cada cambio de estado corre de forma asíncrona, así que es muy probable que en la llamada de tu función, aún no se encuentre el estado con tus datos disponible. Te recomiendo que si es el caso crees tu callback con un useCallback y dependiente de grillaData, adicional, dentro de el clausure puedes trabajar directamente con response

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa que podrías hacer es tener un useEffect que se lanzara cuando cambiara *grillaData*, algo así como:

```javascript
const [grillaData, setGrillaData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        getGrillaApi().then((response)=>{
            setGrillaData(response);
        })
    
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if(grillaData && grillaData.length > 0) {
   pressed('Lun', 0);
  } 
}, [grillaData])
```

Comment: Si quieres ver más casos e info sobre como funciona useState, aquí van una serie de videos: https://www.lemoncode.tv/curso/react-use-state